# Image should fill up width to the left of a right-floated div

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a float:right div embedded in a container. The float:right div takes up a constant width, but its height is variable. There can be any variety of html elements within the container, outside of the float:right div.

Here's a jsfiddle depicting a comparable scenario, where an image within the container is wide enough, that it's being pushed below the float:right div (something I'm trying to avoid): https://jsfiddle.net/a13ym4eo/3/

```
#container {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#floated {
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}

#container img {
  float:left;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

When there is an image element inside of the container, outside of the float:right div, I'd like width of the rendered image element to be the width of the container div, minus the width of the float:right div (i.e. to have the float:right div, and the content outside of it, side by side, in cases where their vertical coordinates overlap). When there is content whose uppermost point is lower than the bottom of the float:right div, the content should fill up 100% of the width of the container. How should I go about doing this in CSS?

Comment: **[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/a13ym4eo/11/)**?

Comment: can you use calc()?
max-width: calc(100% - 100px);

Comment: Your fiddle shows the image being pushed below #floated, as does mine. I'd like the image and #floated to be side by side.

Comment: @Boa [ https://jsfiddle.net/8zuf7jdo/ ] looking something like this one ??

Comment: @sankorati - that may solve the issue of putting the image and #floated side by side, in cases where their vertical coordinates overlap, but the other part of the criteria is that in cases where the top of the image is below the bottom of #floated, the image's width should be the same as the width of the container. Can the calc solution be elaborated to handle both of the above criteria, without getting javascript involved?

Comment: @MostafaBaezid - as per my comment above, that fulfills the first, but not the second part of the criteria. To fulfill the second part, the second image in this fiddle, should fill up 100% of the container's width: https://jsfiddle.net/6thpotzj/1/

Comment: @Boa make them different id or class https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/6thpotzj/2/

Comment: If it's always the first image that needs to be handled with the floated div you could use first-of-type https://jsfiddle.net/6thpotzj/3/

Comment: @MostafaBaezid - to use that solution, you'd have to know in advance which images' top pixels are below the floated div's bottom pixels - as far as I know, there's no a priori way of doing that.

Comment: How you mean when you say _Where the vertical coordinates of the content exceed the float:right div_? ... As you defined the image width to be 100% - 100px, it will always down size, until your for example tell it to not be less wide than 300px ... and if you have a rule like that, @media query will solve the problem for you

Comment: @LGSon - I've edited the question to clarify that part.

Comment: So what you say is when an image, or a div, is the first element, it should be side-by-side with the floated one, but if there is some text first and then an image, or a div, and its top position is below floated one's bottom, it should be full container width?

Comment: @LGSon - there may be any number of images or amount of text that's within the vertical bounds of the floated div, and thus, should be less than 100% of the container's width. There may also be any number of elements that are outside of the vertical bounds (i.e. below) the floated div (this is the content that's 100% of the container's width).

Comment: Ok, well, the problem, as I see it, is that you want one, or many, element(s) to "know" where it is positioned vertically relative to another element, and that can't be done using CSS as it doesn't have such intelligence ... script does though, so the answer to your question is, _you can't do this with CSS alone_

Comment: @LGSon - thanks! I suspected that this might require a javascript + CSS solution, but wanted to run it by the CSS gurus, to be certain.